# Unable to find CSS in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have generated component using cli

```
"ng generate component registration"
```

it created following files

```
registration.component.html
registration.component.scss
registration.component.spec.ts
registration.component.ts
```

Now, I haved added a css class in scss file

```
.loginBox {
 width: 260px;
}
```

Now in the html file

```
<p class="loginBox"> test </p>
```

It pointed out that `loginBox` is undefined CSS in my IDE and when I tested in `ng serve` it didnt show the css was applied.

When I do autocomplete on the `class=` I saw there are alots of css that I didnt add such as `L0, L1, L2, L3` ....so where does those css coming from and why doesnt my local css work? Edit: those css seems like bootstrap css or somewhat buildin css there are something like `mat-action-row` or other type of css I dont think I included them.

The ts file I have included `styleUrls: ['./registration.component.scss']`

Edit: even if I added it the global `styles.scss` it is still says the loginBox is undefined CSS. It is likely some config or something is missing....I cant figure out what it is...

Edit:
registration.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.scss']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

registration.component.scss

```
.loginBox {
  /* color: #4C4633; */
  /* font-size: 12px; */
  /* margin-bottom: 10px; */
  /* padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px; */
  width: 260px;
}
```

registration.component.html

```
<p class="loginBox">
  registration works!
</p>
<div class="loginBox"> test </div>
```

Above registration folder..

app.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: RegistrationComponent}
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [RegistrationComponent],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [PreviousUrlService, {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have you built your project's css? `scss` files aren't normally loaded in production; they need to be built into a `css` file.

Comment: by build you mean just 'ng build' ? it doesnt work after i did a ng build

Comment: Can we see the actual error?

Comment: There is no error. This is exactly what IDE pointed out. 'Multiple markers at this line
- Undefined CSS class (loginBox).
- 1 changed line'

Comment: Could you possibly share  the component's ts file to check if there are any minor mistakes somewhere?

Comment: I have added some info let me know if any more info is needed.

Comment: your angular version ? are you seeing any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Which ide you're using? if you're using webstorm then invalidate caches and restart

Comment: I am using eclipse IDE with codemix plugin, angular version 6

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7845#issuecomment-302326549). Use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the @component definition.

Answer (score 0):

is scss correctly read? try to run this command

`ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss`

then, re-run you project

Comment: I have this included in my Angular.json  ` "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```css
:host ::ng-deep{
  .loginBox {
    width: 260px;
  }
}
```

Comment: could you add a bit more context to your answer? What's this supposed to solve and/or why are you recommending it?